# Uninstall Skimage on Mac?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, scikit-image

I installed skimage for python 3.x on my Mac.
http://scikit-image.org

How can I uninstall this completely?

Comment: if it was installed with `pip`, `pip uninstall scikit-image` should remove it

Comment: Try pls: pip3 uninstall scikit-image